# Revit C# change Family Type

Tags: c#, revit-api, revit

I'm trying to change the family in the project. New family loads successfully but throws and exception 
*Autodesk.Revit.Exceptions.InvalidOperationException: 'This Element cannot have type assigned.'* 
when i try to ChangeTypeId of the old Family to new family GetTypeId();

```
    public void ReplaceTitleblock (Document cdoc)
    {
        string targetName = "TITLEBLOCK_AHMB";

        Family oldFamily = (from element in new FilteredElementCollector(cdoc).OfClass(typeof(Family))
                                           where element.Name == targetName && element.IsValidObject
                                           select element as Family).FirstOrDefault();

        Family newFamily;

        if (oldFamily != null)
        {
            cdoc.LoadFamily(newTitleblockPath, out newFamily);
            ElementId newElId = newFamily.GetTypeId();
            oldFamily.ChangeTypeId(newElId);
        }
```

any help on how to do this?

thanks, 
Luka

Comment: ElementId newElId = newFamily.GetTypeId(); returns -1

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work.

I'm now iterating through FamilyInstances of the Family and replacing the FamilySymbol with new one

```
            foreach (FamilyInstance fam in oldFamilyInstancesFilter)
            {
                FamilySymbol newSymbol = cdoc.GetElement(newFamily.GetFamilySymbolIds().FirstOrDefault()) as FamilySymbol;
                fam.Symbol = newSymbol;
            }
```

i know there's only one symbol hence FirstOrDefault() method